# Format input value in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, input

I'm trying to write a directive that automatically formats a number in the `<input>` but the the model isn't formatted. 
Getting it to work is fine, on load the value in the input is displayed as 1,000,000 and 1000000 in the controller, however when typing only the `ngModel.$parsers` function fires.
The only time when the `ngModel.$formatters` fire is when the directive gets loaded and when the value is 0.

How can I make it work on keypress(I've tried binding to keypress/keyup but it doesn't work).

Here's my code:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []).directive('filterInput', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

            ngModel.$parsers.push(function fromUser(text) {
                return parseInt(text.replace(",", ""));
            });

            ngModel.$formatters.push(function toUser(text) {
                console.log($filter('number')(text));
                return ($filter('number')(text || ''));
            });

        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Here is working example where we use `unshift`:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []).directive('format', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;


            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {
                return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue)
            });


            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');
                elem.val($filter(attrs.format)(plainNumber));
                return plainNumber;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

The HTML seems:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="test" format="number" />
```

See Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/2776/)**</kbd>

Hope its help

Comment: Any ideas why having the parser later in the chain breaks the formatting ?

Comment: @Gepsens can you explain what do you mean under `parser later in the chain `?

Comment: I mean the array of $parsers or formatters, it was because of directive priority basically. I made a directive that takes a formatting and parsing expression and pipes it on the model expression.

Comment: @Gepsens you can set priority to directive (by default its 1) Maybe this example might help you: http://jsfiddle.net/6HcGS/443/

Comment: Hey Maxim, thanks and yeah it's what I did right away. I added an option to clone the input field (with the name attr) as well, so that this directive might be used on a static form. However, it seems like there's need for a Priority Manager provider for cases like that one that override default behavior. For instance, I added a caret manager along that directive to offset the cursor after the parser added a space, and already had to manage priorities. Can't imagine what a mess it'd be for a complex use case

Comment: If I want to add a decimal point like 150.33, I need to push '.' twice. Why is that? Anyway to 'fix' that?

Comment: How would you do this with an ``<input type="number">``?  I tried, but it fails: http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/3957/

Comment: `viewValue.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')` try this expression, hope this will work better

Comment: Im love the solution you have done, i have one issue is there an expression that can replace with "."(dot) instead of ","(comma) because its default in europe values that the "."(dot) is a thousand separator and the ","(comma) is a decimal separator?

Comment: Can you please explain to me why this uses `unshift` instead of `push`? `unshift` takes almost twice as long on benchmarks and doesn't seem to add anything.

Comment: @Clark -- `push` puts on **end** of array, `unshift` on **start** of array. [Order is important](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers) because $parsers, the functions are executed "in array order", but $formatters, "in **reverse** array order".

Comment: For my own benefit, the major insight here is this line in the $parser function: `  elem.val($filter(attrs.format)(plainNumber)); ` While $parsers functions are triggered when user changes DOM value (via 'input' event) , setting val() with Javascript does not trigger the 'input' event. If setting val() *did* trigger and 'input', it would trigger the $parser, which would set val()... infinite loop. The effect of val() safely changes only what the user sees in browser.

Comment: it does fail when you type same alphabet twice in a row. you can see the alphabet the parse doesn't trigger.

Answer (score 5):

This module works fine for me.

https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks

Example:

```
<input type="text" name="field" ng-model="number" ui-number-mask>
```

Comment: It looks good, although it uses the same method that was described in the accepted answer. Also this wasn't around when the question was asked.

Answer (score 1):

Small edit to Maxim Shoustin's answer below as per the answer to this question:
[AngularJS formatter - how to display blank instead of zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599184/show-blank-on-backspace-rather-than-zero-in-number-formatted-angularjs-input/25601992#25601992)

Only change is to ensure that the input is blank rather than zero on the deletion of the last number:

```
   ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
        console.log(viewValue);
        if(viewValue){
            var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');
            elem.val($filter('number')(plainNumber));
            return plainNumber;
        }else{
            return '';
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2n73j6rb/

Comment: If I start with $scope.test = ''; I still get 0. How do I start with a blank input box? http://jsfiddle.net/magician11/947cb12h/

Answer (score 0):

I created this directive solution for myself which does:

1. Initializes input to 0.00 on focus.
2. Compatible with Template-Driven and ReactiveForm.
3. Removes/undo any non-digit entry.
4. Prevents empty input.
5. Paste 123ab4d5, outputs: 12345.
6. Divides every thousand by a ,
7. Backspace/Delete compatible.
8. Lets enter/remove in the middle.
9. Positive int only.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Recommended**: Use [maxLength] to limit user to a certain length.

```
 <input [maxLength]="9" appPriceUsd>
```

**Here is the directive:**

```
// Format USD by Reza Taba
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';


@Directive({
  selector: '[appPriceUsd]'
})
export class PriceUsdDirective {
  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) { }

  @HostListener('focus') initializeValue(): void {
    if (this.elRef.nativeElement.value === '') {
      this.elRef.nativeElement.value = '0.00';
    }
  }

  @HostListener('keyup') formatUsd(): void {
    let value: string;
    value = this.elRef.nativeElement.value as string;
    value = this.removeNonDigtis(value); // remove all non-digit values
    value = this.addDecimalPoint(value); // Add . to the -2 index
    value = this.applyDecimalPipe(value); // to divide every thousand
    this.elRef.nativeElement.value = value;
  }

  removeNonDigtis(value: string): string {
    let inputArray: string[] = [];
    const digitArray: string[] = [];

    // 12a34b to ["1", "2", "a", "3", "4", "b"]
    inputArray = value.split('');

    // remove any non-digit value
    for (const iterator of inputArray) {
      if (/[0-9]/.test(iterator)) {
        digitArray.push(iterator);
      }
    }

    return digitArray.join('');
  }

  addDecimalPoint(value: string): string {
    const inputArray = value.split(''); // ['0', '.', '0', '0']
    inputArray.splice(-2, 0, '.'); // place decimal in -2
    return inputArray.join('');
  }

  applyDecimalPipe(value: string): string {
    console.log(value);
    return value === '' || value === '.'
      ? '0.00'
      : this.decimalPipe.transform(value, '1.2-2');
  }
}
```

Hope it helps. Enjoy coding.