# AngularJS formatter - how to display blank instead of zero

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, angularjs-directive

Please see this previous question:
[Format input value in Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890364/format-input-value-in-angularjs)

The issue I am having is that (as is the case in the fiddle in the answer to the question above, i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/811/), hitting backspace on a single number remaining in the input leads to a zero appearing rather than clearing the input.

Fiddle directive code:

```
fessmodule.directive('format', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;


            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {
                return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue)
            });


            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');
                elem.val($filter('number')(plainNumber));
                return plainNumber;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

I would appreciate any suggestions for how to alter the directive in the fiddle so that you don't have to hit backspace twice to clear the input.

Comment: a tad confusing.  i would refphrase.  this your question is being examined for closing for being too vague or offtopic.

Comment: I have edited the question to try to make it clearer.  In truth this would have been better as a comment to the previous question but I did not have enough to rep to comment on that question.  I will go back and add an answer to the previous question with a link to the fiddle provided by wickY26.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply put an if-else condition to your directive and it is done...

```
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
            console.log(viewValue);
            if(viewValue){
                var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');
                elem.val($filter('number')(plainNumber));
                return plainNumber;
            }else{
                return '';
            }
        });
```

here is working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2n73j6rb/)

Comment: Thanks @wickY26!  I had tried a simple if but obviously missed something.