# Angularjs : How to format a number in an input

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs and I want to format the numbers display in my inputs.
To display a simple value with specific format I do :
 `{{myValue:number:2}}`,
but with an input :
`<input type="text" ng-model ="myValue"/>` I don't know how to do.
If I do : 
`<input type="text" ng-model ="myValue|number:2"/>` I am getting an error :

> Error: [ngModel:nonassign] Expression 'myValue|number:2' is
>   non-assignable. Element:

Thank you.

Comment: `ng-model` needs `string` value.. For solving this issue you need to write custom directive & then use `$formatter` & `$parser` to update `ng-model` value

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890364/format-input-value-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

I tried with normal javaScript approach, to achieve your requirement.

I added `ng-change="floatNumber(mynumber)"` in the `input`, so in every change the function will fire and do the calculation there:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="mynumber" ng-change="floatNumber(mynumber)">

  $scope.floatNumber = function(mynumber) {
    var retNum = '';
    if (mynumber.indexOf('.') > 0) {
      var splitNum = [];
      splitNum = mynumber.split('.');
      //if (splitNum[1].length === 0)
      //retNum = mynumber + '00';
      if (splitNum[1].length === 1) {
        retNum = mynumber + '0';
        $scope.mynumber = retNum;
      }
    }
  };
```

Sample Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/YyTqc28c23ccITQGshAX?p=preview