# AngularJS number filter greater than 1000

Tags: angularjs, html

In Angular I have this line

```
<input type="number" value="{{ price.fare + price.tax | number:2 }}" />
```

But as soon as `price.fare` and `price.tax` add up to `1000`, I get this error:

`The specified value "1,000.00" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?`

How can I fix this?

Comment: validation error has thown because `type="number" ` expects only number field, and by exceeding above `1000` it adds `,` in field value.. you should go for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19890485/2435473) for achieving what you want

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do.
Do you want to filter the input so user won't be able to insert a value > 1000?

Comment: The user should be able to insert values > 1000. I want to see 2 digits and comma separated thousands.

Comment: So you need to use  text input. A comma does not fit the validation for `type=number`

Comment: Posted my own way of doing this @PankajParkar ...

Comment: Solution in a plunkr here - https://plnkr.co/edit/7cY2Lm?p=preview tl;dr remove type=number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove type=number in total column.  Plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/7cY2Lm?p=preview

```
  <div ng-controller="myController as price">
      <h1>AngularJS number filter greater than 1000</h1>
      <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36118671/angularjs-number-filter-greater-than-1000">Stack Overflow </a>
      <br/>
      Fare: <input type="number" ng-model="price.fare" />
      <br/>
      Tax: <input type="number" ng-model="price.tax" />
      <br/>
      Total: <input value="{{ price.fare + price.tax | number:2 }}" />
      <br/>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  this.fare = 990;
  this.tax = 20;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Solved similar type of error 'The specified value "xxxx" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?'  by replacing **value** with **ng-value** in html tag.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses. I came up with following solution which works the way I need it to:

```
.filter('currencyFilter', ['$filter', function() {

  return function(amount) {
    var value = amount.toString();

    if(value.indexOf('.') > -1){
      value = value.substr(0, value.indexOf('.') + 3);
    }

    value = value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

    return value;
  };
}]);
```