# Applying a filter with ng-model realtime Angular

Tags: angularjs, format, currency

I have a input tag like this

```
 <input currency  type="text" class="form-control amount" ng-model="loan.total">
```

what I want to do is I want to view this "total" value as separated 3 by 3(4000 -> 4 000).loan.total value should be 4000. but it should be visible as 4 000. tried to apply a directive but didn't work.

is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display a value as currency outside the input like this:

```
<input  type="number" class="form-control amount" ng-model="loan.total"> {{loan.total | currency}}
```

Comment: Thanks. filter works but outside of the input box :(. I want it to be inside inputbox

Comment: Check out the answer to this then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890364/format-input-value-in-angularjs it requires building a custom directive.

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like you want is an input mask.

Maybe try this:

https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks

It has a ui-money-mask directive.

For example:

Make sure you include the script tag and add the module dependency:

```
<script src="angular-input-masks-standalone.min.js"></script>
<script>
  angular.module('yourAppName', ['ui.utils.masks']);
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, I thought it was the documentation for the directive would be good enough, but I added an example.