# Angular JS Format $scope variable attached to input with 2 decimal number on load

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

So I have the following scenario:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.number  =7.00;
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">  
    <div class="div-table-row">
        <input type="number" step="0.01" ng-model="number" />
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Even though I set the number variable with 2 decimals angular is removing both 0s after the dot. How can I prevent this and show the whole number 7.00 inside the input. I know you can use the filter on spans but what about inputs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format input value in Angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890364/format-input-value-in-angularjs)